# Django Firefox debugging

Tags: jquery

I know its kind of question that you see often but I don't see a correct.

I have written a Django code and testing it with Firebug..I mean im trying to play with the ids created but for some reason..

I have this id-nav in my .html file..but this code is always giving error,

$('nav').hide()

Error:

TypeError: $("nav").hide is not a function

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Django Bookmarks | {% block title %} {% endblock %}
    </title>
    <link rel=stylesheet" href="/site_media/style.css"
        type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/site_media/jquery.js"></script>
        {% block external %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
    <a href ="/">home</a> |
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="/save/">submit</a> |
        <a href="/user/{{ user.username }}/">
            {{ user.username }}</a> |
        (<a href="/logout">logout</a>)
    {% else %}
        <a href="/login/">login</a>
        <a href="/register/">register</a>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    <h1>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $('#nav').hide()..this command gives me this error-TypeError: $("#nav") is null

Comment: This question is poorly tagged - it is neither a Django question nor a firefox question; it is a jQuery question.

Answer (score 0):

Use $('#nav').hide()

You forgot the '#'. $('nav') looks for  whereas $('#nav') looks for id="nav".

Comment: $('#nav').hide()..this command gives me this error-TypeError: $("#nav") is null

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

> {% load static %}

before your statics. And to serve your static files (js, image etc.) as in .js here,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "assets/js/jquery.js" %}"></script>`

This will solve the problem.
For more info, please check here [managing statics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).